# UCC28C42: TI simulated ,Resistor Heated

Tags: power, amplifier, resistors, transformer, pwm

I am using an  UCC28C42 in my circuit.

I need a clarification of some resistor. I am converting 48V to 24V. If my load increases to 4.5A then Resistor is getting heated up.(Circled part)

I used higher wattage resistors(1k 2W), too.

PFA of Ckt
[image: circled resistor is heating]

Comment: circled part:-,Resistor is getting burned out wen i increase load.

Comment: this does not belong in a comment . . please edit your post instead

Comment: and: what's the Wattage of the resistors you've used? you say you used "higher wattage", but forget to mention *how* high the wattage was.

Comment: thanks jstola.1k ohm 2W

Answer (score 0):

It's a part of core reset circuitry. It should get hot when no load is present and it should be cool when max. load is present.
It is possible that you swapped the polarity of the output secondary coil? See dots orientation:

[image]

EDIT:

MY bad. It' not a reset circuitry, rather a RC snubber to damp the MOSFET ringing. Your values are not appropiate.

Comment: Core reset is mainly (on a flyback design) achieved with the secondary load current and not what you say. Those components are to catch the excess energy not coupled to the secondary and snub it.

Comment: that's what I said

Answer (score 0):

D20 is a flyback clamp diode.

The parts encircled ought to be like a T=500us snubber, while yours is ~ 360ms in schematic and too lossy.

1k//1k//330uF = 165ms snubber is just as bad or worse for loss.

Check primary L and compute  sqrt(L/C)=2pi f and reduce C significantly and choose RC= 500 us.  ( I think)

Comment: Hi ,Thanks man...can I use 2W

Comment: ?? 10nF//50k Try 1/4W